# Is there an equivalent of Javascript's hasOwnProperty() in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, attributes

I want to check whether an object has an attribute as a direct (i.e. not inherited) property, similar to Javascript's [`obj.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). How can I do this in Python? `hasattr()` seems to return inherited attributes as well.

Comment: Why do you want to check this? JS is prototype-based not inheritance-based, which is why it supports that functionality; it makes no sense in a more traditional OOP structure.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `hasattr(MyClass, '__bases__')` is `True`, but `dir(MyClass)` lists no `'__bases__'` (see the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47914724/275088)).

Comment: @planetp That's because `__bases__` is a member of the metaclass, see `dir(type(MyClass))`

Comment: @Matias yes, but `type.__bases__` is `(<class 'object'>,)`.  The actual base classes must be stored somewhere in the class itself.

Comment: Show us your code. How did you create the object, how did you use https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html to query it, and what alternate result did you want to see instead? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `dir(MyClass)` doesn't show `__bases__` because `dir` is designed for interactive convenience, not for consistency or usefulness in an actual program. ["Note: Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "in"?

If you have a class object you can check if an attribute was defined by:

```
"what_you_want_to_search" in object.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can try using if/in.
e.g
obj = {"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}

if "a" in obj:
your code.

please ref https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_check_if_dictionary_item_exists.asp